# Using Json.NET To Deserialize Multiple Types of Objects Into One List

Tags: c#, json, list, parsing, 2d-games

I'm having trouble using Json.NET, which I moved to from LitJSON. It works quite well, other than the fact that I cannot separate different types of objects to force them to use different constructors.

For example, I could do this with LitJSON:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalAmountOfItems; i++)
    {
        if (itemData[i]["type"].ToString() == "Weapons")
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < itemData[i]["array"].Count; j++)
            {
                database.Add(new Item((int)itemData[i]["array"][j]["id"], itemData[i]["array"][j]["title"].ToString(),
                                  itemData[i]["array"][j]["weaponType"].ToString(), (bool)itemData[i]["array"][j]["stackable"], itemData[i]["array"][j]["slug"].ToString(),
                                  (int)itemData[i]["array"][j]["damage"], (int)itemData[i]["array"][j]["durability"])); //Reads the component in quotes for object
                                                                                                                        //with address 'i'. Creates new item based
                                                                                                                        //on this data.
                                                                                                                        //Note: If using only one .Add method, all items in database must follow it's pattern.
            }
        }
        else if (itemData[i]["type"].ToString() == "Food")
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < itemData[i]["array"].Count; j++)
            {
                database.Add(new Item((int)itemData[i]["array"][j]["id"], itemData[i]["array"][j]["title"].ToString(),
                                  (bool)itemData[i]["array"][j]["stackable"], itemData[i]["array"][j]["slug"].ToString(),
                                  (int)itemData[i]["array"][j]["hungerAmount"]));
            }
        }
        else if (itemData[i]["type"].ToString() == "Medicine")
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < itemData[i]["array"].Count; j++)
            {
                database.Add(new Item((int)itemData[i]["array"][j]["id"], itemData[i]["array"][j]["title"].ToString(),
                                  (bool)itemData[i]["array"][j]["stackable"], itemData[i]["array"][j]["slug"].ToString(),
                                  (int)itemData[i]["array"][j]["healAmount"]));
            }
        }
        else if (itemData[i]["type"].ToString() == "Equippable")
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < itemData[i]["array"].Count; j++)
            {
                database.Add(new Item((int)itemData[i]["array"][j]["id"], itemData[i]["array"][j]["title"].ToString(),
                                  (bool)itemData[i]["array"][j]["stackable"], itemData[i]["array"][j]["slug"].ToString(),
                                  (int)itemData[i]["array"][j]["armorAmount"], (int)itemData[i]["array"][j]["insulationAmount"]));
            }
        }
        else if (itemData[i]["type"].ToString() == "Resource")
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < itemData[i]["array"].Count; j++)
            {
                database.Add(new Item((int)itemData[i]["array"][j]["id"], itemData[i]["array"][j]["title"].ToString(),
                                  (bool)itemData[i]["array"][j]["stackable"], itemData[i]["array"][j]["slug"].ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

This allowed me to use one container class (Item) to store data for a variety of different objects, using different constructors. How would I go about doing the same thing in Json.NET?

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
public void ConstructWeaponDatabase()
    {
        using (Stream s = FileOp.Open(@"Data\Misc\Weapons.json", FileAccessMode.Read)) //Opens file
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(s)) //Declares new reader
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd(); //Reads 'r' and its stream (s) to the end of the file.
                weaponDatabase = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Misc.Weapon>>(json); //Json.NET magic to place items from file
            }                                                                            //into list.
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it only takes in one format of "Weapon" (Container class that functions in the same way as the Item class shown above). How can I make it so different constructors are used depending on the Weapon in the JSON file?

The reason I cannot use LitJSON for this is that it is not a portable library, which is a requirement for all libraries used with Duality (A C# game engine).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived `JsonConverter` and override the `ReadJson`method to implement your custom logic, and then pass an instance of this converter to `Deserialize`- have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base)

Also, you might want to consider using `Item` as a base class and use derived classes to represent your different items (`Food`, `Medicine`, etc.) instead of using a single class to represent conceptually different objects.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks!